# Using Java 7 with official Google Appengine Maven plugin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, maven-plugin, java-7

> *I'm having trouble using the [official Maven Plugin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven) and Java 7 with Google Appengine.*

## Configuration

My project configuration `pom.xml` is quite simple:

In the properties section I configure:

```
<gae.version>1.7.4</gae.version>
```

And later on I use the plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${gae.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

## Error message

Whenever I run `mvn appengine:update` I get the following error:

> Unable to update app: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.

## My attempt to solve it

Of course, I tried to fix this issue. Running

```
mvn appengine:update --use_java7
```

or

```
mvn appengine:update -D--use_java7
```

didn't help, because the flag is not used for the Maven plugin, but instead for the `appcfg` script.

*How do I pass the flag to the script, so that I can use Java 7 (or is there anything else I can do)?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App Engine Java 7 Support is currently for Trusted Tester and not available to public yet, you can apply  Trusted Tester at [here](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/viewform?id=13UvQiEjr7ob-QXMSFch5LByQN8vHa70Rl98g8ipCf9c).

Fortunately the latest official maven plugin does implement this feature, see the [AbstractAppCfgMojo.java](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/source/browse/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/AbstractAppCfgMojo.java#134):

```
... ...

/**
 * Use the App Engine Java 7 runtime for this app.
 *
 * @parameter
 */
protected boolean useJava7;

... ...

if (useJava7) {
  arguments.add("--use_java7");
}

... ...
```

You can use the following plugin configuration in pom.xml to enable Java7 support:

```
</build>
  <plugins>
    ... ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${gae.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <useJava7>true</useJava7>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanx. Bonus question: how can I change the address of the devserver? I found the class [DevAppServerRunner](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/source/browse/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/DevAppServerRunner.java#87) and the attribute `address`, but setting `<address>192.168.178.27</address>` didn't work (it still uses `localhost`).

Comment: If you mean making your dev_appserver accessible from other computer on your network, use `<address>0.0.0.0</address>`.