# appengine-maven-plugin 1.7.5 seems to have incomplete java7 support because of lagging deps

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

I'm trying to use the new Google plugin in maven for GAE.

All is running smoothly, unlike with the old plugin.

All but the deploy.

The first alarming thing is that starting from an empty `.m2` (I deleted it to be sure that no old versions were messing with me) and during the initial download phase of `mvn appengine:update`, maven says

```
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-tools-sdk/1.7.4/appengine-tools-sdk-1.7.4.jar (16762 KB at 788.5 KB/sec)
```

Then, if I run `mvn appengine:update`, it says

```
[INFO] Updating Google App Engine Application
********************************************************
There is a new version of the SDK available.
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.7.5
Timestamp: Fri Jan 11 00:56:53 CET 2013
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.7.4
Timestamp: Tue Dec 11 12:41:31 CET 2012
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
```

When I check my .m2 folder, I got

```
mog@becca:~/.m2/repository/com/google$ tree -L 2 appengine/
appengine/
├── appengine
│   ├── 1.7.4
│   └── 1.7.5
├── appengine-api-1.0-sdk
│   └── 1.7.5
├── appengine-api-stubs
│   └── 1.7.5
├── appengine-java-sdk
│   └── 1.7.5
├── appengine-maven-plugin
│   └── 1.7.5
├── appengine-testing
│   └── 1.7.5
└── appengine-tools-sdk
    └── 1.7.4
```

This seems to show that the dependencies o the 1.7.5 plugin are incomplete: some lag behind in 1.7.4. The annoying part is that it seems to prevent me from using the automatic java 7 detection feature of the 1.7.5 plugin, as shown below:

When I use `mvn appengine:update`, I get a warning:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
```

This warning, and the fact that I get an error 500 when I go to my website which then is explained by the following log:

```
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@15a4523{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~trashnao/1.365599992371450729}
org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: fr/univnantes/atal/web/trashnao/Controller : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: fr/univnantes/atal/web/trashnao/Controller : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:656)
```

Lead me to think that the used `appengine-tools-sdk-1.7.4` doesn't support yet automatic java 7 detection through the `pom.xml` file.

As said in [this video](https://developers.google.com/events/48092530/) by the devs themselves, this feature of automatic detection of the java 7 target is available in the 1.7.5 plugin.

Trying the solution given in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675058/using-java-7-with-official-google-appengine-maven-plugin/14677222#14677222), I get this message instead of the one about the boostrap class:

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'com.google.appengine.tools.compilation.DatastoreCallbacksProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
```

I'd like any suggestion on how to fix that. Ie, how to make the `mvn appengine:update` goal use the `--java_7` option in its invocations of appcfg ([related doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/java7))

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675058/using-java-7-with-official-google-appengine-maven-plugin/14677222#14677222) helps.

Comment: @yorkw: When I wrote ''Trying the solution given in that question'', I meant to put a link to the question you mention on the ''that question'' part, but forgot to do so. As I say one line after that, it still gives me an error, but a different one. As a workaround I only use java 6 atm :(

Answer (score 2):

I can fix this, if you'd like to file an issue and see progress, feel free to do so here : https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/list and I'll keep it updated.

Edit : Fixed in 1.7.6 and using the enforcer plugin to make sure it doesn't happen again.

Comment: Nice :) [here is the link](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=13&thanks=13&ts=1362467561) for other visitors.